# how to find probability of one or more events to happen from an incomplete data set

Tags: statistics

I have a dataset that gives information of a population. For instance, I know the fraction of people that are males (`M`) and that are within a certain age range (`A`), `P(M & A)`, and then I know the fraction of males that live in a certain area (`L`), `P(M & L)`.

What I'm interested in computing is `P(M & A & L)`, which is the fraction of people that are males, are within a certain age range and live in a certain area.

Using Baye's formula I can say that

```
P(M & A & L) = P(M & A | L) P(L)
```

But my dataset only gives `P(L)` and not `P(M & A | L)`. However, if I assumed that `M & A` and `L` are independent I have

```
P(M & A | L) = P(M & A) P(L)
```

How large is the error on `P(M & A | L)` if I make this assumption. Do you know of any other method I could use to estimate `P(M & A | L)` without assuming independence?

Comment: When you say you have a dataset, do you mean you only have those descriptors of the dataset (the ones you mentioned)?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

[Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) applies to conditional probabilities. 
$
     P(A|B) = \frac{P(A).P(B|A)}{P(B)} 
    $

The question you have posed is one of multiple events occurring together. If the events can be considered to be independent of each other, then,

```
P(A & B & C) = P(A).P(B).P(C)
```

In your question above,

```
P(M & A & L) = P(M & A).P(L) = P(M).P(A).P(L)
```

Based on the data provided by you, you should have these probabilities or can derive them by appropriate summations.

Let's say that .1 probability of males are between 1-10 years of age. Further, probability of males in location L is 0.2. So the probability of males in 1-10 years of age in Location L is 0.1 X 0.2 = 0.02 . This is assuming that all locations have the same probability distribution of age ranges.

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I'm asking. I'm interesting in knowing `P(M & A | L)` and I know that `M` and `A` are dependent (I also know P(M & A)), but I don't know if `L` depends on `M & A`, so they only thing I could do was to assume `P(M & A | L) = P(M & A) P(L)`. So now I need to understand how bad this assumption is.